# If f is analytic in the unit disk and $|f(z)|\leq \frac{1}{1-|z|}$ then $|f'(0)|\leq 4$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I need to prove that if $f$ is analytic in the unit disk and $|f(z)|\leq \frac{1}{1-|z|}$ for z all $z\in D_1(0)$  then $|f'(0)|\leq 4$. This is my proof and I need to verify this.

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\overline{D}_{1-(\frac{1}{n+1})}(0) \subset D_1(0)$. Thus $f$ is analytic in the closed disk $\overline{D}_{1-(\frac{1}{n+1})}(0)$. Then by Cauchy's estimate $$|f'(0)|\leq \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-|1-\frac{1}{n+1}|}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{n}$$. 
This is where I am sort of stuck. Since the radius of $\overline{D}_{1-(\frac{1}{n+1})}(0)$ is minimum when $n=1$ substituting this to the above I can get that $$|f'(0)|\leq4$$. How can I improve this? Thanks

Comment: The only improvement I see is to use arbitrary real radii $0 < r < 1$ instead of only $\frac{n}{n+1}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. You get $$\lvert f'(0)\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{r(1-r)},$$ and you can find the maximum of $r(1-r)$ on $(0,1)$ at $r = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for that tip.But, is what I have done wrong? r=1/2 is same as taking n=1 in my case but I guess I did not put it forward in a very nice way.

Comment: No, what you've done is not wrong. It is unsafe in the sense that you're not guaranteed that $$\inf\{b(r):0<r <1\} =\inf\left\{b\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right):n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\right\}$$ a priori, where $b(r)$ is the bound the Cauchy estimates yield for the radius $r$, the left hand side could be strictly smaller than the right (and for some bounds on $\lvert f(z)\rvert$ that happens). In some sense you've just been lucky that you have equality for $\lvert f(z)\rvert\leqslant\frac{1}{1-\lvert z\rvert}$, but I guess if you wouldn't have gotten the desired bound, you'd have tried other radii.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thankyou for that explanation